# Edit HTML Comment Text using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible that we could edit text enclosed inside an HTML comment using Javascript or JQuery. For example if I have a comment like:

```
<!-- This is a comment -->
```

then is it possible to change text 'This is a comment' using JQuery or Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course. That's the whole point of jQuery, manipulating the DOM. See this https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Ah. I see you have edited your post (or Rory did :) You want to change what's inside a comment. That's completely different.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate through `childNodes` of the comment's parent element, filter the commentNode and change it's value by resetting `nodeValue` property:

```
$('#parent').contents().each(function() {
    if ( this.nodeType === 8 ) {
       this.nodeValue = 'changed value';
    }
});
```

[Using vanilla JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/mkrtm38b/):

```
var parentNode = document.getElementById('parent');

[].forEach.call(parentNode.childNodes, function(el) {
    if ( el.nodeType === 8 ) {
       el.nodeValue = 'changed value';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace()` function like this:

```
var x =  $.trim($('#container').html()).replace('<!--','').replace('-->','');
```

There is also a [plugin](http://chivil.com/uncomment/) which you can use to uncomment is a jQuery plugin that will allow you "move" commented HTML code into the DOM

**EDIT:-**

If you want to remove it from the DOM as Rory commented then you can try this:

```
 $('*').contents().each(function() 
 {
        if(this.nodeType == Node.COMMENT_NODE) 
        {
            $(this).remove()
        }
 });
```

Comment: Note that this will make the comment of the text visible in the DOM, it will not retain the comment and change the text within it - which is what the OP seems to be looking to do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan:- Updated my answer to remove it from the DOM as well.